# Create in memory and show or change live element

Tags: javascript, html

I am reordering a `<table>`.

I wondered if it is faster to

1) create a new, reordered table in memory, then replace the old one in the DOM

2) do the reordering (changing row positions) on the live DOM tree?

I have seen that stuff like downloading an image is done in the background to a dummy element, which will be later added to the DOM. I understand that it is to mitigate I/O time, and keep the page more responsible.

In this specific case, I wondered if doing the same to help with the processing time would work? My reasoning is that at each re-order step the table would have to be re-flown.

I did not test it, yet, my reason to ask it here, because this whole question may be flawed from the beginning, which may be obvious to someone more experienced with JS/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually rearranging Nodes is cheaper than replacing them. But somethimes the difference is negligible so that it ain't worth the effort; that rerendering is just simpler.

If it's just about sorting the rows in a table,

- I'd create an Array of the `<tr>`
- sort that Array
- add them in order to a `document.createDocumentFragment()`
- and then that fragment *(and with that, all rows at once)* to the table

to avoid multiple render cycles, as they are way more costly than most JS codes.